# no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

currently I'm trying to set up a simple app in Ruby on Rails. I've migrated the db, seeded it and am now stuck at the following error.

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String

Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
2: <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
3: <![endif]-->
4: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
6: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

It seems like the asset tags helpers are not working properly or returning nil (if that's even possible)?

Answer (score 23):

I hotfixed this error by adding the following line to my application.rb:

```
ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root = ''
```

The error is most likely due to a bug in my rails version which is 3.0.12.

Comment: It is a known bug in your rails version and it will never be fixed in Rails 3.0.x, see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9619