# How to run Ruby on Rails 3 with ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an easy fix, how I could continue an old rails 3-0.20 installation under ruby 2.0?

The first error, caused by this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
```

is

```
ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
```

An upgrade of the rails version would be the best, but unfortunately it is not possible in my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044008/no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-string may be related

Comment: I don't think that error is due to Ruby 2.0 with you version of Rails. In fact, according to the link that @rogerpack provided, it's potentially an issue that occurs sometimes with Rails 3.0.20 specifically. Perhaps try the suggested solution there and see if that clears up your problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hotfix the problem with the following line at the end in application.rb

```
ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root = ''
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.  After drilling down into the `stylesheet_link_tag` method, I found that the issue comes from here

```
# actionpack-3.0.20/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:749
if has_request && include_host && !source.start_with?(controller.config.relative_url_root)
```

The problem is `String#starts_with?`.  In 1.9.3, that method will handle a `nil` as an input.  2.0.0 does not allow that.

```
ruby-1.9.3> 'whatever'.start_with? nil
=> false

ruby-2.0.0> 'whatever'.start_with? nil
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

It's probably also true that later versions of Rails set the value to '' if it's not set to prevent this issue.  The hotfix mentioned above does fix the issue, but the root cause *is* differences between 1.9.3 and 2.0.0.