# No implicit conversion of nil into string Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rets

I have some code that accesses an MLS listing service and downloads pictures into AWS.  I am getting the error on MLS login.  I'm on ruby 2.2.2p95 and rails 3.2.22.

My code:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
    :access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  )

  puts 'connected to AWS'

  client = Rets::Client.new({
   login_url: LOGIN_URL,
   username: LOGIN,
   password: PASSWORD,
   version: VERSION
   })

 begin
    client.login
#  rescue => e
#     puts 'Error: ' + e.message
#     exit!
 end
```

The error:

```
➜  LiveByTransit git:(master) ✗ rake update_pics --trace
** Invoke update_pics (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute update_pics
66
connected to AWS
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.3/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:55:in `read_memory'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.3/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:55:in `parse'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.3/lib/nokogiri/xml.rb:64:in `parse'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/rets-0.9.0/lib/rets/parser/error_checker.rb:17:in `check'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/rets-0.9.0/lib/rets/http_client.rb:20:in `http_get'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/rets-0.9.0/lib/rets/client.rb:344:in `http_get'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/.bundle/gems/rets-0.9.0/lib/rets/client.rb:63:in `login'
/home/nitrous/code/LiveByTransit/lib/tasks/update_pics.rake:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
.bundle/binstubs/rake:16:in `load'
.bundle/binstubs/rake:16:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => update_pics
➜  LiveByTransit git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
➜  LiveByTransit git:(master) ✗ rails -v
Rails 3.2.22
```

In my code above, you'll see I commented out the error rescue.  If I comment back in, the error looks like this:

```
➜  LiveByTransit git:(master) ✗ rake update_pics --trace
** Invoke update_pics (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute update_pics
66
connected to AWS
Error: no implicit conversion of nil into String
➜  LiveByTransit git:(master) ✗
```

I've tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044008/no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-string) with no change.

Comment: What is contained in the VERSION variable?

Comment: Wait are you able to connect? But after going through objects it is failing? Is 66 the number of images?

Comment: The VERSION variable is the version of RETS used by the MLS.  I am not able to connect, and I think it is a problem with my code vs a problem with the MLS.  I am able to connect to the MLS outside of my app with the same code.  66 is the number of listings that need a picture update.  This code used to work, but I updated my version of ruby and I think this is creating problems.

Comment: @tomb did you fix this? What did you do?

Comment: @knagode, the code is working now, and it looks like I log into the Rets server first, then establish the connection to AWS. Not sure if that is the silver bullet. Happy to send a code sample if that doesn't work.